# boto3 module is installed in conda virtual environment but get module not available

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I use terminal within `pycharm`, and I have conda virtual environment setup in `pycharm`, and also `conda activate` the correct virtual environment in the terminal within the `pycharm`, and I make sure I have pip installed boto3. but when I run `hug -f api.py -p 9000` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'`. what's the issue with this?
[image]